# Initializing custom ComboBox (WinForms, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, custom-controls

I wasn't able to find any proper guidance in documentation, so I'm asking here.
I have custom combo box (inherited from the default), which - in run-time - should load items (enum) from remote data source.

Which method (event?) to use, to initialize list of items? I definitely do not want to do it in parent container (i.e. Form).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand what you want. I asume that you create a UserControl. In this case, have you tried to do it in the constructor of the control? I mean:

```
public class BetterComboBox : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
    public BetterComboBox(List<SomeObject> list)
    {
         // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
         InitializeComponent();

         //you can pass over the list from parameter or initialize it right here.
         //if you need to call a store procedure or something, do it here.
         this.DataSource = list;
    }

    //other methods that you need to override or write
}
```

You can also read about Handlers, if you need to handle some other event done in the view side. Hope it helps! =)

Comment: thank you... i am well aware of custom constructors and handlers... the point is, you can not do it in constructor, as it is called in IDE upon placing on form, therefore causing possible cascade of events in datasource etc. my question was, if there is some better place i have not found; due to no responses (except yours) here, i came to conclusion, it is not. then, wrapping my initialisation code with IDE barrier code (which i personally hate) was my solution.